# Spring Batch non-transactional step has commit count of 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am currently trying to investigate the total number of transactions of my spring batch job.

As I can see, a `StepExecution` has a property `commit_count` that tells how many transactions were commited by the step.

I have a job that consists of two steps:

- Read a file and map the content to Java objects ( = should be non-transactional, right?)
- This step uses a Tasklet, which is only called once. So only one transaction is going to be created for this according to my understanding. Basically, the step does some specific processing of the created objects and persists them to the database afterwards ( = should be transactional, right?)

After the execution of my step I can see that both steps have a `commit_count` of 1. 
But I expected only the second step to have a `commit_count` of 1. The other one should have a `commit_count` of 0, right?

I know that, next to the business transactions, Spring does some own transactional stuff in order to persist the job and step execution metadata and so on. But i have read on the internet that this is not technically wrapped in a transaction and thus I don't expect it to be included in the `commit_count` of a step, right?

In order to see the total number of commited transactions I also have tried to configure `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor: TRACE` but this just logs lots of the following log statements

```
Completing transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]
Getting transaction for [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]
```

Completing transaction sounds to me like a transaction has been commited. I am seeing lots of statements like this in the logs, so does this mean my batch job is creating lots of transactions? Actually I have expected the batch job metadata update would be enclosed in a single transaction..

Can someone please explain this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

A commit is made after every chunk. The chunk size of Tasklet(non-chunk based) is always 1. That is reason why commit count is 1 for Tasklet(non-chunk based)

Comment: It does a commit even though I am not doing anything with the database? Does that even make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `Tasklet#execute` is executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch. This is explained in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep). If the business processing inside the tasklet is not transactional, you can use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager` for that tasklet. But technically speaking, there will be a `ResourcelessTransaction` anyway, hence the commit count is at least equal to 1, which explains what you see in the corresponding step execution.

> I know that, next to the business transactions, Spring does some own transactional stuff in order to persist the job and step execution metadata and so on. But i have read on the internet that this is not technically wrapped in a transaction and thus I don't expect it to be included in the commit_count of a step, right?

I don't know where you read that, but technically speaking there will be a transaction for each call to `Tasklet#execute`. The transaction manager is a mandatory property for a `TaskletStep`.

That said, there are other transactions driven by Spring Batch during the execution flow of the job to check/update meta-data in the job repository.